# Degradation in performance of pump

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, dc, fluid-pump

I recently purchased a Dc pump rated 3 to 6v~ On connectig it with a 9v battery(cheap one) it works well for 5~~minutes continuous after which its performance degrades to a level of it where it's useless I don't understand is there a fault with my 9v battery or the pump,, I did check the voltage of my battery after 5 minutes it gave me a reading close to 7.8 but my pump barely worked

Comment: You are lucky that the battery is "wimpy" - otherwise it could be akin to "My car engine is redlined at 6000 RPM. When I operate it at 9000 RPM it starts to overheat and make strange noises. Why?"

Comment: You deleted your other question. This is a a bad idea. People are trying to help, if you answer their questions they can help you achiever your aims. Deleting questions makes people less likely to spend time helping you.

Comment: I thank you for your generosity but I think I'm not knowledgeable enough to post anything on community rn maybe in the near future I will look into it

Comment: Your  "Battery for low current and voltage" question could have been answered if you had described your application in detail. You must know what you are trying to achieve. Tell us what you wish to achieve and we can assist you with doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about a pump like this in the photo? It's rated (advertise in AliExpress) to use 130-220 mA, which is too much for a 9V battery. At 9v the pump will draw even more current than this.

A 9v battery can supply about 450 mAh, but it will be more comfortable with a lower current.

This behaviour that you are describing (~ 5 min untill the performance degrades) seems to be normal, when using this battery. Probably the 7.8V reading you talk about was taken with the pump off, but with the pump on the voltage could be even lower.

There's no fault to the pump or the battery, maybe it's just because they're not compatible. I suggest you to try another power source for your project. A wallwart from a old cell phone could be perfect. If you really need to use batteries, try using a batch of three or four AA cells.

By the way, those pumps are rated with a very low lifespam, just about 500 hours.

[image: Cheap low voltage pump]

Comment: @Shariq If the answer was helpful to you, you could "reward" the time I spent in writing it just "accepting" the answer as useful.

Comment: Yes it's the same pump,I noticed that the current that pump draws remains constant throughout how ever the voltage that my battery provides tends to decrease after 1,2 minutes keeping the battery under no load condition for about an hour kends to increase the volatage provided by the same battery however this is very weird can you please explain this

Comment: Batteries have chemical energy and convert it to electrical energy. The maximum rate for this conversion is proportional to the size of the battery. A 9v battery has six tiny 1,5V cells inside it; each of those cells is smaller than a AAA cell. So, a 9v battery has hard time when connected to a device that draws a current at a high rate like 100 mA or more. When you disconnect the circuit and let the battery "rest" for a few hours, it recover some of its voltage, as the chemicals inside rearrange and change their concentration. This is not weird, it's just the expected behaviour of batteries.

Comment: If I'm not wrong is it because of internal resistance of a battery?

Comment: Yes. The internal resistance increases when high current is drawed, and decreases when you let the battery "rest". New batteries have lower internal resistance than older ones, too.